# Get details record as property of master

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Please consider this code:

```
var res = (from a in ent.Orders
           where a.OrderID < 10252
           select new
           {
               OrderId=a.OrderID,
               OrderDate = a.OrderDate,
               OrderDetails=ent.Order_Details.Where(o=>o.OrderID == a.OrderID).ToList()
           }).ToList() ;
```

When I ran this code I got this error:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NorthwindModel1.Order_Detail] ToList[Order_Detail](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NorthwindModel1.Order_Detail])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I want to get `Orders` with a list of their details.

How I can do this with one linq statement?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make a model class as shown below :

```
public class ViewModelClass
{
     public int OrderId{ get; set; }
     public int OrderDate { get; set; }
     public List<NorthwindModel1.Order_Detail> OrderDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

and then in your query :-

```
var res = (from a in ent.Orders
           where a.OrderID < 10252
           select new ViewModelClass
           {
               OrderId=a.OrderID,
               OrderDate = a.OrderDate,
               OrderDetails=ent.Order_Details.Where(o=>o.OrderID == a.OrderID).ToList()
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm using Northwind database and create an entity framework model based on it

Comment: I made some update please change and try again @Kerezo

Comment: Ok Thanks that's my mistake.I use your code but I get first error:(

Comment: `Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF you can .Include("OrderDetails") when you request your Orders. Though I admit I dont remember if northwind database has the relationships set.

Something like:

```
 var dbctx= new NorthwindContext();
 var orders= dbctx.Orders.Include("OrderDetails").Where(o=>o.OrderID<10252).ToList();
```